# Cannot fetch data from MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am trying to fetch data from my Mongodb database in which I have an already defined collection (stupid simple for only test purposes). But I do not manage to get the data out. The console.log only gives me [].

sadjkhfskadjhfksdajhfkajsdhfkjsadhfsakdf
lkasdhfkjasdhfkjjasdhfkj
lksadhfkjasdhfkjsadhf

### model1.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// schema
const MySchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    desc: String

}, {collection: 'Test'}
);

const Test =  mongoose.model('Test', MySchema)

module.exports = Test;
```

### route1.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Tests = require("../../models/model1.js")

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.get('/cs/test', function (req, res){

         Tests.find({}, (error, result) => {
            res.json(result)
            console.log(result);
     });
   });
```

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const http = require('http');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'html');


app.use('/static', express.static('static'));
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);

//register the Handlebar partials
hbs.registerPartials('views/partials');

// just keep the databse open for every request
require('./database');



require('./routes/cs/route1.js')(app);


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listen to 3000");
});
```

### database.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const url ="mongodb://localhost:27017/thewalls";

// To hide warning message about promise
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//Connect Mongoose
mongoose.connect(url, { useMongoClient: true });

mongoose.connection.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("Database connected!");
});


module.exports = mongoose;
```

### database

[database screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQqk3.png)

Comment: Can we see your router and how you setup the mongo connection/express server

Comment: Do you actually call `mongoose.connect()` at some point?

Comment: added app.js and database.js so you can have a look!